# Benchmarking Quick Sort Algorithm. Iteration function not working properly

Tags: java, iteration, benchmarking

I am currently trying to benchmark a Quick Sort algorithm using both Iteration and Recursion. My problem is with my output, my recursive function works properly and sorts the elements. My iterative function is not working properly though. Here are 2 sample output's and my code that I have. You will see that the iterative function works sometimes but not every time. How do I fix this problem?

#### Output 1

> ITERATIVE SORT
> 464 10 775 896 997

> 464
> 10
> 775
> 896
> 997
> array index out of bounds
> The array was not sorted correctly:
> 464 at index 0 and 10 at index 1

> ITERATIVE SORT
> 929 225 730 915 991

> 929
> 225
> 730
> 915
> 991
> array index out of bounds
> The array was not sorted correctly:
> 929 at index 0 and 225 at index 1

> ITERATIVE SORT
> 292 94 382 474 495

> 292
> 94
> 382
> 474
> 495
> array index out of bounds
> The array was not sorted correctly:
> 292 at index 0 and 94 at index 1

> ITERATIVE SORT
> 207 349 612 719 962
> RECURSIVE SORT
> 207 349 612 719 962

> ITERATIVE SORT
> 655 157 366 806 865

> 655
> 157
> 366
> 806
> 865
> array index out of bounds
> The array was not sorted correctly:
> 655 at index 0 and 157 at index 1

> Data Set Size (n): 5
> Iterative Selection Sort Results: Recursive Selection Sort Results:
> Average Critical Operation Count: 0 Average Critical Operation Count: 1
> Standard Deviation of Count: 0 Standard Deviation of Count: 2
> Average Execution Time: 800 Average Execution Time: 160
> Standard Deviation of Time: 1600 Standard Deviation of Time: 320 *

#### Output 2

> ITERATIVE SORT
> 11 280 305 356 970
> RECURSIVE SORT
> 11 280 305 356 970

> ITERATIVE SORT
> 287 288 459 649 774
> RECURSIVE SORT
> 287 288 459 649 774

> ITERATIVE SORT
> 341 446 569 882 902
> RECURSIVE SORT
> 341 446 569 882 902

> ITERATIVE SORT
> 181 308 382 513 627
> RECURSIVE SORT
> 181 308 382 513 627

> ITERATIVE SORT
> 744 53 917 941 978

> 744
> 53
> 917
> 941
> 978
> array index out of bounds
> The array was not sorted correctly:
> 744 at index 0 and 53 at index 1

> Data Set Size (n): 5
> Iterative Selection Sort Results: Recursive Selection Sort Results:
> Average Critical Operation Count: 0 Average Critical Operation Count: 10
> Standard Deviation of Count: 0 Standard Deviation of Count: 7
> Average Execution Time: 0 Average Execution Time: 1400
> Standard Deviation of Time: 0 Standard Deviation of Time: 990

**SortMain.java**

```
public class SortMain {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] sizes = {5};    //, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 5000, 7500, 10000, 15000};
        new BenchmarkSorts(sizes);
 
    }
}
```

**BenchmarkSorts.java**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
 
public class BenchmarkSorts {
 
    private final int NUMBER_OF_RUNS = 5;
 
    private int[] array;
 
    private int iterativeCount = 0;
    private int recursiveCount = 0;
 
    private int iterativeIndex = 0;
    private int recursiveIndex = 0;
 
    private long iterativeTime, recursiveTime;
 
    private int [] iterativeCountLog = new int[NUMBER_OF_RUNS];
    private int [] recursiveCountLog = new int[NUMBER_OF_RUNS];
    private long [] iterativeTimeLog = new long[NUMBER_OF_RUNS];
    private long [] recursiveTimeLog = new long[NUMBER_OF_RUNS];
 
    private static QuickSort quickSort = new QuickSort();
 
     public BenchmarkSorts(int[] sizes) {
         // Creates benchmarks based on the input array size
         IntStream.range(0, sizes.length).forEach(i -> new BenchmarkSorts(sizes[i]));
     }
 
     private BenchmarkSorts(int n) {
         // Outer loop 50 times (NUMBER_OF_RUNS)
         IntStream.range(0, NUMBER_OF_RUNS).forEach(i -> {
             array = new int[n];
             // Inner loop based on the array size (n)
             IntStream.range(0, n).forEach(j -> {
                 Random random = new Random();
                 array[j] = random.nextInt(1000);
             });
             // Runs the sort and produces output if an UnsortedException is found
             try {
                 runSorts();
             } 
             catch (UnsortedException e) {
                 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
             }
         });
         displayReport(n);
    }
 
    private void runSorts() throws UnsortedException {
        // Runs iterative sort
        int returnCount = quickSort.getCount();
        long returnTime = quickSort.getTime();
        System.out.println("\nITERATIVE SORT");
        int[] newArray1 = quickSort.iterativeSort(array, 0, array.length -1);
        quickSort.printArr(newArray1, newArray1.length);
        System.out.println("\n");
        quickSort.checkSortedArray(newArray1);
        iterativeCount = iterativeCount + returnCount;
        iterativeTime = iterativeTime + returnTime;
        iterativeCountLog[iterativeIndex] = iterativeCount;
        iterativeTimeLog[iterativeIndex] = iterativeTime;
        iterativeIndex++;
 
        // Runs recursive sort
        System.out.println("\nRECURSIVE SORT");
        int[] newArray2 = quickSort.recursiveSort(array, 0, array.length-1);
        quickSort.printArr(newArray2, newArray2.length);
        quickSort.checkSortedArray(newArray2);
        returnCount = quickSort.getCount();
        returnTime = quickSort.getTime();
        recursiveCount = recursiveCount + returnCount;
        recursiveTime = recursiveTime + returnTime;
        recursiveCountLog[recursiveIndex] = recursiveCount;
        recursiveTimeLog[recursiveIndex] = recursiveTime;
        recursiveIndex++;
    }
 
    private void displayReport(int arraySize) {
 
        // Sets local variables
        double iterativeAverageCount = 0;
        double iterativeAverageTime = 0;
        double recursiveAverageCount = 0;
        double recursiveAverageTime = 0;
        double iterativeVarianceCount = 0;
        double iterativeVarianceTime = 0;
        double recursiveVarianceCount = 0;
        double recursiveVarianceTime = 0;
        double iterativeSDCount = 0;
        double iterativeSDTime = 0;
        double recursiveSDCount = 0;
        double recursiveSDTime = 0;
 
        // Calculates averages
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RUNS; i++) {
            iterativeAverageCount += iterativeCountLog[i];
            iterativeAverageTime += iterativeTimeLog[i];
            recursiveAverageCount += recursiveCountLog[i];
            recursiveAverageTime += recursiveTimeLog[i];
        }
 
        iterativeAverageCount = iterativeAverageCount / arraySize;
        iterativeAverageTime = iterativeAverageTime / arraySize;
        recursiveAverageCount = recursiveAverageCount / arraySize;
        recursiveAverageTime = recursiveAverageTime / arraySize;
 
        // Calculates standard deviations
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RUNS; i++) {
            iterativeVarianceCount += Math.pow(iterativeAverageCount - iterativeCountLog[i], 2);
            iterativeVarianceTime += Math.pow(iterativeAverageTime - iterativeTimeLog[i], 2);
            recursiveVarianceCount += Math.pow(recursiveAverageCount - recursiveCountLog[i], 2);
            recursiveVarianceTime += Math.pow(recursiveAverageTime - recursiveTimeLog[i], 2);
        }
 
        iterativeVarianceCount = iterativeVarianceCount / arraySize;
        iterativeVarianceTime = iterativeVarianceTime / arraySize;
        recursiveVarianceCount = recursiveVarianceCount / arraySize;
        recursiveVarianceTime = recursiveVarianceTime / arraySize;
 
        iterativeSDCount = Math.sqrt(iterativeVarianceCount);
        iterativeSDTime = Math.sqrt(iterativeVarianceTime);
        recursiveSDCount = Math.sqrt(recursiveVarianceCount);
        recursiveSDTime = Math.sqrt(recursiveVarianceTime);
 
        // Produces output
        System.out.println("Data Set Size (n): " + arraySize +
                "\n\tIterative Selection Sort Results: \t\t\t\t\tRecursive Selection Sort Results:" +
                "\n\tAverage Critical Operation Count: " + Math.round(iterativeAverageCount) +
                "\t\t\tAverage Critical Operation Count: " + Math.round(recursiveAverageCount) +
                "\n\tStandard Deviation of Count: " + Math.round(iterativeSDCount) +
                "\t\t\t\t\tStandard Deviation of Count: " + Math.round(recursiveSDCount) +
                "\n\tAverage Execution Time: " + Math.round(iterativeAverageTime) +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\tAverage Execution Time: " + Math.round(recursiveAverageTime) +
                "\n\tStandard Deviation of Time: " + Math.round(iterativeSDTime) +
                "\t\t\t\t\t\tStandard Deviation of Time: " + Math.round(recursiveSDTime));
    }
}
```

**QuickSort.java**

```
public class QuickSort implements SortInterface {  
 
    private static int count = 0;
    private static long timeStart = 0;
    private static long timeEnd = 0;
 
    private static void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j) {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
    public static int partition(int[] array, int low, int high) {
 
        int pivot = array[high];
        int i = (low - 1);
 
        for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++) {
            if(array[j] <= pivot) {
                i++;
                swap(array, i, j);
            }
        }
        swap(array, i + 1, high);
        return i + 1;       
    }
 
    //  function to recursively sort the list
    public int[] recursiveSort(int[] array, int low, int high) throws UnsortedException {
        count++;
        timeStart = System.nanoTime();
        int i = partition(array, low, high);
 
        if(low < i - 1) {
            recursiveSort(array, low, i - 1);
        }
 
        if(high > i) {
            recursiveSort(array, i, high);
        }
        timeEnd = System.nanoTime();
        return array;
    }
 
    public int[] iterativeSort(int[] array, int low, int high) throws UnsortedException {
        count++;
        timeStart = System.nanoTime();
        int stack[] = new int[high - 1 + 1];
        int top = -1;
 
        stack[++top] = low;
        stack[++top] = high;
 
        while (top >= 0) {
            high = stack[top--];
            low = stack[top--];
 
            int pivot = partition(array, low, high);
 
            if(pivot - 1 > 1) {
                stack[++top] = 1;
                stack[++top] = pivot - 1;
            }
 
            if(pivot + 1 < high) {
                stack[++top] = pivot + 1;
                stack[++top] = high;
            }
        }
        timeEnd = System.nanoTime();
        return array;
    }
 
    public int[] printArr(int array[], int n)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
        return array;
    }
 
    public int getCount() {
        int result = count;
        count = 0;
        return result;
    }
 
    public long getTime() {
        long time = timeEnd - timeStart;
        timeEnd = 0;
        timeStart = 0;
        return time;
    }
 
    public void checkSortedArray(int[] list) throws UnsortedException {
        if(list == null || list.length <= 1) {
            System.out.println("Array is sorted: null or 1 element");
        }
 
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length - 1; i++) {
            if (list[i] > list[i + 1]) {
                try {
                    for (int j = 0; i < list.length - 1; j++) {
                        System.out.println(" " + list[j]);                      
                    }
                    System.out.println("array is sorted");
                }
                catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                    System.out.println("array index out of bounds");
                }
                throw new UnsortedException("The array was not sorted correctly: \n" +
                        list[i] + " at index " + i + " and " + list[i + 1] + " at index " + (i + 1));
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int[] iterativeSort(int[] array) throws UnsortedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int[] recursiveSort(int[] array) throws UnsortedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

**SortInterface.java**

```
public interface SortInterface {
 
    int[] iterativeSort(int[] array) throws UnsortedException;
    int[] recursiveSort(int[] array) throws UnsortedException;
 
    int getCount();
    long getTime();
}
```

**UnsortedException.java**

```
public class UnsortedException extends Exception {
 
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
    public UnsortedException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In

```
public int[] iterativeSort(int[] array, int low, int high) 
     throws UnsortedException {
    ...
            int pivot = partition(array, low, high);
             
            if(pivot - 1 > 1) {
                stack[++top] = 1;
                stack[++top] = pivot - 1;
            }
    ...
```

the `if` should instead be

```
            if(low < pivot - 1) {
                stack[++top] = low;
                stack[++top] = pivot - 1;
            }
```

BTW, your recursive version is slightly sub-optimal:

```
    if(high > i) {
        recursiveSort(array, i, high);
    }
```

This works, but you can exclude the pivot index (`i`) here as it's already in the right place, so

```
    if(high > i + 1) {
        recursiveSort(array, i + 1, high);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the optimized recursion code. Unfortunately the iterative method still produces arrays that aren't organized [low,...,high]

Comment: Possibly because your loop in `checkSortedArray()` overruns.